# writing sql to find aggregation

Tags: sql, database, aggregation

I have these relations

```
Entry
-----
id
creationdate
grade


Subject
------
id
name
```

and join table

```
Entry_Subjects
------------
entry_id
subject_id
```

I need to create the sql to find average grade of entries belonging to a particular subject ( say 'java') on a particular creationdate

I tried the following

assume id for Subject 'java' is 2

```
SELECT creationdate,
    avg(grade) 
FROM (SELECT * 
     FROM Entry 
     WHERE id IN
         (SELECT id 
          FROM Entry_Subjects 
          WHERE subject_id =2
         )
     )
GROUP BY creationdate;
```

I get the error

```
subquery in FROM must have an alias
```

I tried to correct this but couldn't

can somebody tell me why this error occurs.. my db knowledge is not that good

Comment: You may want to do a join and take the average rather than a sub query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably want JOINs instead of nested SELECTs.

```
SELECT
    creationdate,
    AVG(grade)
FROM Entry e
INNER JOIN Entry_Subjects f
    ON e.id = f.entry_id
INNER JOIN Subject s
    ON f.subject_id = s.id
WHERE s.name = 'java' --this is where you replace 'java' with a variable to search by name
GROUP BY creationdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done using analytical functions

```
select a.creationdate,avg(a.grade) over (partition by a.creationdate order by a.creationdate) as avg_grade
from entry a,subject b,entry_subjects c
where a.id=c.entry_id and b.id=c.subject_id
and upper(b.name)='JAVA';
```